# Login/logout dynamic

Tags: php, dynamic, authentication, logout

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
echo "Logout";
} else {
echo "Login";
}
?>
```

i need someting like this thath i adapted to this bur still wont work...

```
    <?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
<p>Ola; <u><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></u>, </p>
<p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>;
}
else {
<p><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login</a></p>;
}
?>
```

Should i put it in a separed frok html code and include it or? Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you want to say and what your actual problem.. but i have checked given url and in my understanding this code may work for you..

```
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
    <p>Ola; <u><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></u>, </p>
    <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
<?php } else{ ?>
    <p><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login</a></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks...

Comment: updated thath code to website still same problem prints bought so the if is not working as it should :x is there a way you could help me like 5 min? skype? Thank you for the attention

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question, but I can see your code has some problems. Try the below.

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
    <p>Ola; <u><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></u>, </p>
    <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login</a></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: i cant put the code working tih is my webpage http://needforgaming.x10.mx/testefinal/home.html  my objective is to say the username of the loged user if he is loged and the logout button next to thath and if not loged in just say login there is the right-top of screen... and if i should call thath php file on html or just paste this code in html